# Android Timer makes ListView ignore clicks sometimes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask

I'm creating a simple little game to practice my coding but I've stumbled into a problem. It's not game breaking but it's certainly annoying. In my game, I have a class Tappable which is what my ListView is populated with. Every time you tap on a ListView element, my OnItemClickListener just adds 1 to the amount you have of a Tappable.

Long story short, I use a custom ArrayAdapter and I have AsyncTask running on a loop with handlers in order to calculate how much money you are making. This implementation of a timed AsyncTask was done so I could put calculations on another thread and then update the UI onPostExecute. However, when I tap on a ListView element, some taps are completely ignored. This happens more severely the lower the interval is between the timed AsyncTasks.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView moneyView;
    ListView tappablesView;
    ArrayList<Tappable> tappables = new ArrayList<>();
    TappableAdapter tappableAdapter;
    double money = 0; // Total amount of money you have
    double time; // Var to do checks on the amount of time to finish AsyncTask

    // Here is the stuff that I use as my Timer.
    int millisecondsToDelay = 30;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public class WorldUpdater extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //This is for checking how long it takes my Tasks to complete
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Var to hold amount to add to money
            double moneyAddable = 0;
            // Go through the tappables arraylist
            for (int i = 0; i < tappables.size(); i++) {
                Tappable t = tappables.get(i);
                // increase the progress to a payout for a tappable
                if (t.getAmount() > 0) {
                    t.updateProgress();
                }
                // add any money that can be collected to moneyAddable
                moneyAddable += t.collectMoney();
            }

            // To be processed in onPostExecute
            return moneyAddable;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Double m) {
            super.onPostExecute(m);

            // add the moneyAddable from doInBackground to the amount of money you have
            money += m;

            // Set the moneyView text to show how much money you have
            updateMoneyView();
            // Tappable progress increased, so show that in the list view
            tappableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Now we see how long the task took
            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

            // If the task took longer than the amount I want it to delay, then say how long it took
            if (time > millisecondsToDelay) {
                Log.i("Timer info", "Too long: " + time);
            }

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new WorldUpdater().execute();
                }
            }, (((long) (millisecondsToDelay - time)) > 0)? (long) (millisecondsToDelay - time): (long) 0);
        }
    }

    public void updateMoneyView() {
        moneyView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "$%,.2f", money));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        moneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Money);
        tappablesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TappablesView);

        // The two tappables in the listview
        tappables.add(new Tappable("Buy me!", .25, 1, 1500));
        tappables.add(new Tappable("Buy me as well!", 1, 2.25, 1000));

        tappableAdapter = new TappableAdapter(this, tappables);
        tappablesView.setAdapter(tappableAdapter);

        tappablesView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // On item click, increase the amount of the tappable that was clicked by 1
                tappables.get(position).buyAmount(1);
            }
        });

        updateMoneyView();

        // Start my timer
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new WorldUpdater().execute();
            }
        }, millisecondsToDelay);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

Here is my Tappable.java

```
public class Tappable {

    private String title;
    private double revenue, cost, revenuePerItem, costPerItem;
    private int progress, progressNeeded, progressStep, amount;
    private boolean canCollect = false;
    private double amountToCollect = 0;

    public Tappable(String title, double r, double c, int ps) {
        this.title = title;
        revenuePerItem = r;
        amount = 0;
        revenue = revenuePerItem * amount;
        costPerItem = c;
        cost = costPerItem * (amount + 1);
        progressNeeded = 100000;
        progress = 0;
        progressStep = ps;
    }

    public void buyAmount(int n) {
        amount += n;
        updateCost();
        updateRevenue();
    }

    public void updateProgress() {
        progress += progressStep;
        if (progress >= progressNeeded) {
            progress = 0;
            amountToCollect += getRevenue();
            canCollect = true;
        }
    }

    public double collectMoney() {
        double amountCollectable = 0;
        if (canCollect) {
            amountCollectable = amountToCollect;
            amountToCollect = 0;
            canCollect = false;
        }
        return amountCollectable;
    }

    public void updateCost() {
        cost = costPerItem * (amount + 1);
    }

    public void updateRevenue() {
        revenue = revenuePerItem * amount;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public int getProgressNeeded() {
        return progressNeeded;
    }

    public double getRevenue() {
        return revenue;
    }
}
```

Here is my TappableAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TappableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<Tappable> tappables;
    private final Resources res;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TappableAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Tappable> t) {
        this.context = context;
        tappables = t;
        res = context.getResources();
        inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tappables.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return tappables.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Tappable t = tappables.get(position);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView titleView, amountView, costView, revenueView;
        titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        amountView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Amount);
        costView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Cost);
        revenueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Revenue);

        ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        titleView.setText(t.getTitle());
        amountView.setText("Amount: " + t.getAmount());
        costView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "$%,.2f", t.getCost()));
        revenueView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "$%,.2f", t.getRevenue()));

        p.setMax(t.getProgressNeeded());
        p.setProgress(t.getProgress());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jake.mypointclicker.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Simple Point Clicker"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Money"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="$123,456,789.00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Money"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/TappablesView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:text="Test Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Revenue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:text="$123,456,789.00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:text="Amount: 123456789" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:text="$123,456,789.00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried many ways of doing my timer. I tried just using Timer with a timertask which had the same effect. Line 25 or so is where my variable for how long to delay is. Lowering that increases the amount of clicks that are ignored. Raising it has the inverse effect but makes the progress bars look less smooth. Like I said, it's not a game braking problem, but I don't understand why the onItemClick is not called sometimes when I try updating the UI frequently. Is the Listener itself on the UI thread and it is being blocked when I update the UI in my AsyncTask?

Comment: I believe your delay is holding up the main thread of the application thereby not allowing any further action to occur. You will have to insert the wait login in a new thread in order to stop it from holding up your application.

Comment: my delay? as in handler.postDelayed itself or the entirety of the handler and the runnable AsyncTask? And how would I insert the "wait login" (what is that by the way) in a new thread?

Comment: I don't have the time to go through all of this code at the moment but I know from past experience that this is usually the case, debug through it and check which thread is holding onto what. Also, login was a spelling mistake, it's supposed to be logic.